# Joomla 3.6 Change the language of the reporting error messages in frontend only?

Tags: joomla-3.x

right now my Joomla 3.6.5 is running:

Portuguese Language in Frontend (site)
English Language in Backend

I wan to keep as that, but I need to change the error messages (in frontend) to english as well. But as my frontend language is setup to Portuguese, the error reporting messages are in Portugues also.

Is there a way to keep using portuguese language to frontend, but the error messages in english?

With Best Regards
Bruno Alecrim

Answer (score 1):

You can make "Language Overrides":

- Select in Backend the Menue "Extensions > Language(s) > Overrides".
- set Filter to "your Language - Administrator"
- Click on Button "New"
- Search for Error Message at bottom left Column check Mark "For both Locations" so Front- and Backend-Message get changed

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I see this solution helps but It seems I need to manually override each error message instead of just change the language, right? Maybe I am wrong, this is what I understood.

Is there a way to simply define the error message in frontend to be in English while the frontend itself be in another language (Portuguese)?

With Best Regards
Bruno Alecrim

Comment: As far as i know you change the Language for the complete Front- and/or Backend and cannot split into different Parts showing different Languages.